# Form themes - Add code at n block_name match

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a front symfony application that takes a serialized symfony form from an API, parses it and finally renders it.

This application is supposed to be dumb, and should not be aware in any way of any remote app's logic.
It just takes json form, and displays it after parsing.

The fields in the serialized form have custom (remote app defined) block names which are then used in front app's form themes to build fields structures.

Said field example :

```
"field_1": {
    "options": {
        "block_name": "block_name_example",
        "label": "Example",
        "required": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "choices": {
            "Choice 1": "1",
            "Choice 2": "2"
        },
        "help_description": "",
        "attr": {
            "name": "field_name_1",
            "short_name": "fieldName1"
        }
    },
    "type": "Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Extension\\Core\\Type\\ChoiceType"
}
```

I would like, in the form_theme block, to add something "the first time this block name is matched" (for example), **without any logic added on the remote app side**, something like :

```
{% block _form_block_name_example %}
    {% if match_occurrence = 1 %}
        {# do something here #}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I know there is many ways (form field extra option, wrap it into a collection type field ...) to solve this through remote app code edits, but I don't want to for various reasons, the main one being to avoid any additional complexity to remote app's code.

Couldn't find a clean way to solve this. Will you be my hero ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though of a pretty clean way to handle this on the front side app only. Stripped to the max the classes from unrelated code & renamed some things to make it as much generic as I could for you.

I added a new extra `first_of_type` option to my fields through form extension, which I set at form's generation. I then use it as a casual option in my form theme's block. Code below.

The form extension :

```
class ExtraOptionsExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Add the width option.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined([
            /* ... */
            'first_of_type'
        ]);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        /* ... */
        $view->vars['first_of_type'] = false;
        if (!empty($options['first_of_type'])) {
            $view->vars['first_of_type'] = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

The FormType :

```
abstract class AbstractType extends BaseAbstractType
{
    /* ... */

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $blockNames = [];
        if (is_array($this->fields)) {
            foreach ($this->fields as $property => $data) {
                $type = $data['type'] ?? null;
                $opts = $data['options'] ?? [];
                if (!in_array($type, $this::TYPES_WITHOUT_EXTRA) &&
                    isset($data['options']['block_name']) &&
                    !in_array($data['options']['block_name'], $blockNames)) {
                    $blockNames[] = $data['options']['block_name'];
                    $opts['first_of_type'] = true;
                }
                $builder->add($property, $type, $opts);
            }
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The form theme block :

```
{% block custom_block %}
    <div class="form-group form-inline {% if not first_of_type %} hide {% else %}">
        {{ form_label(form, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Could still be improved to provide more information on element's position compared to it's pairs (not only the fact it's first).